# Manually triggering alert in Google Cloud Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to be able to programmatically trigger alerts in Google Cloud Monitoring. Basically I have a watchdog that I want to execute certain actions based on multiple criteria. One of those actions is that I want it to trigger a new alert in Google Cloud Monitoring.

Is there a smooth way to do this?

So far my best guess is:

1. Setup an alert policy on a custom metric (like isTriggeringAlert>0)
2. Write the actions to a log ("[ALERT]: ....") and use Cloud Monitoring to catch that log

Both works, but was wondering if there is a programatic way to trigger instead? I haven't found anything in the Python SDK for Cloud Monitoring (just how to create monitoring policies)

Regards,
Niklas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has been [requested](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186026191), but isn't available yet.
As a workaround, you can try writing appropriate data into timeSeries using this [API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/create).